# Will turning off my laptop's screen often burn out the inverter?

Tags: display

I have a program on my computer that automatically turns off my laptop's screen when I lock it - and I lock my computer almost whenever I leave it.The inverter in it has recently gone bad, prompting me to purchase a replacement one. Before I put it in, I wanted to know if turning my laptop's screen off this often would burn out the inverter?

Comment: Millions of laptops have their screens set to black out when unused for a period of time.  I've never heard of this causing a hardware problem, and I would quite shocked if it did, since blacking out the screen is an important power-saving measure.  (Of course, this says nothing about the possible misbehavior of your special program, but it would have to be doing some naughty stuff to cause damage.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible it might hasten its demise, but unless it's very cheap it's unlikely to actually cause this kind of problem in and of itself.  Inverters going out on consumer laptops after a few years is not all that uncommon, I'm afraid.

Comment: How much will it hasten it? Because I'm wondering if I need to remove this program from my system...

Comment: It's hard to say without laboratory testing on that exact laptop.  If it were me, I wouldn't worry about it, but I would never install an application like that in the first place.  Why not just lock the screen and set the monitor sleep timeout to some low threshold (2-3 minutes?)

Comment: Because of this.. http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/windows-7-turn-off-the-display-does-not-work-when/741bc127-edc6-4928-9409-2a36aaa3d0c1

Comment: Then disable the screen saver (people still use those?)